# How to Deploy a unity working app to the HoloLens 1?

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

I have followed some guidelines found online on how to build a unity application using MRTk2 and saw which bugs to ignore, nevertheless, after building my solution I am unable to deploy it to the HoloLens 1.

I built the solution using:

- II2Cpp backend & have
- installed SDK 10.0.18632.30
- Set minimum SDK to 10.0.10240.0
- Target SDK to Latest Installed

And The build succeeded!

When I open the solution on Visual Studio 2017, and try to deploy(release, x86) I get the errors bellow:

- > Error   MSB3073 The command ""D:\Project\Virtual%20Guided%20Assembly%20V3\Code_VGA.v3b\Builds\WSAPlayer\Il2CppOutputProject\IL2CPP\build\il2cpp.exe" --libil2cpp-static --compile-cpp -architecture=x86 -configuration=Release -platform=winrt -outputpath="D:\Project\Virtual%20Guided%20Assembly%20V3\Code_VGA.v3b\Builds\WSAPlayer\build\bin\Win32\Release\GameAssembly.dll" --data-folder="D:\Project\Virtual%20Guided%20Assembly%20V3\Code_VGA.v3b\Builds\WSAPlayer\build\bin\Win32\Release\" -cachedirectory="D:\Project\Virtual%20Guided%20Assembly%20V3\Code_VGA.v3b\Builds\WSAPlayer\build\obj\il2cppOutputProject\Win32\Release\" -generatedcppdir="D:\Project\Virtual%20Guided%20Assembly%20V3\Code_VGA.v3b\Builds\WSAPlayer\Il2CppOutputProject\Source" --additional-defines=WINDOWS_UWP --additional-defines=UNITY_UWP --additional-defines=UNITY_WSA_10_0 --additional-defines=UNITY_WSA --additional-defines=UNITY_WINRT --additional-defines=PLATFORM_WINRT -dotnetprofile=unityaot -verbose --map-file-parser="D:\Project\Virtual%20Guided%20Assembly%20V3\Code_VGA.v3b\Builds\WSAPlayer\Il2CppOutputProject\IL2CPP\MapFileParser\MapFileParser.exe"" exited with code 3.
- > Error   MSB4018 The "GetOutOfDateItems" task failed unexpectedly.

[image: Here is a picture of my environment for a better understanding of my problem]

Comment: Did you make sure you click `Start without Debugig` instead of simple `Start`?

Comment: Hi @Irek I did try starting the application using Ctrl + F5, which is suppose to start without debugging and I still have the same error.

Comment: Did you try to deploy to Hololens over Wifi? I'd recommend trying that and see if the error is still there.

Comment: The problem persists when trying to deploy over Wifi too...

Comment: I also tried to deploy straight from unity over network, but that fails with "Authentication failed! Device not found | No Response Header", although I am able to connect to Device Portal trough the same IP and credentials.

Comment: Have you paired the Hololens with your PC? I assume that you changed the device type in VisualStudio to `Remote Device` and you added the IP address in `Project Properties -> Debbugig -> Machine Name`? 
In your Unity `Project Settings - Player - Other Settings` do you have `Scripting Runtime Version` as `.NET 4.x Equivalent` and `API Compatibility Level` as `.NET 4.x`? I'm asking those question as so far it seems we have quite simliar options, and I did not experience the same error as you.

Comment: @Irek I have all that set. Which version of unity are using? I am using 2018.3.10f1

Comment: I use `2018.3.14f1`, but don't expect this to be the issue. I'm not sure how to help at this stage. Could you maybe share a link to the tutorial you followed to set everything up?

Comment: I followed the instruction here https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/GettingStartedWithTheMRTK.html

Comment: did you try to Build->Clean, Build->recompile before deploying? Also did you try to uninstall the old app from the HL first before deploying again?

Comment: @derHugo I have tried all that and the problem persisted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many trials, I have decided to move the project to a new location and I was able to build it and deploy to the HoloLens.
Apparently the problem was being caused by the encoded space "%" on the project path, removing that allowed me to build and deploy the application successfully!

You can see the difference on how the solution were being loaded into VS17 in the picture below:

[image]

Comment: The `%` is not a `%` but actually an encoded `SPACE` within the path.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, GameAssembly.lib was not getting created.so i tried to create Unity build inside C-drive (in which visual studio 2019 is installed ) and now Unity is creating GameAssembly.lib. I am using Unity 2019 .2 , IL2CPP backend , visual studio 2019 and MRTK 2 and created build for Hololens 1.